# Symfony 2.6.5. Custom UserProvider. User not logged out when User->isEqualTo returns false

Tags: symfony

I'm building a application with Symfony 2.6.5. I have built my own User Provider following [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html) and [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html).

My User class implements AdvancedUserInterface and EquatableInterface.
isEqualTo returns false if either password, username or isEnabled has changed.
I serialize id, username, password, isEnabled and a few custom properties.

It all works pretty good. Except for the following:

I can login (without RememberMe), everything looks good. I've verified that refreshUser() in my user provider is called on every request as is isEqual() in user.

If I directly change the username in the database and hit refresh, I'm not logged out. My view displays the user name and that changes to the new value from the database. Likewise I am not logged out if I manually change the password hash in the database. I have verified that isEqualTo() returns false and $this->setAuthenticated(false) happens in AbstractToken.

It does logout on the next refresh if I change isEnabled to false.

Either I'm doing something wrong, the [documentation here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#understanding-serialize-and-how-a-user-is-saved-in-the-session) is wrong, I'm misinterpreting it or there is a bug in Symfony.

It's not a big deal. The fact that isEnabled gives me a way to log someone out is good but I'd like to understand this better.

Thanks

EDIT: I just discovered that I'm not the only one seeing this.

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/13870

I probably should have looked there first.

Comment: I suppose you implemented EquatableInterface on User

Comment: Yes EquatableInterface is implemented. I should have mentioned that. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

I have come to the conclusion that this is a documentation issue rather than a bug. Explanation at the bottom of https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/13870 and a new issue for the docs at https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/5419